# Nova Launcher: Lost the App Drawer Icon

Tags: nova-launcher

I've installed Nova Launcher on an old phone (1st Gen MotoX). I'm trying to child-proof it by disabling most of the default apps and clearing the home screens with nothing that a child shouldn't be getting into. After updating some Nova Settings, going back to home screen rendered the App Drawer icon missing (the one in the middle of the dock at the bottom of the screen).

Interested in a fix and how to prevent this from happening in the future.

Comment: Try this: https://www.reddit.com/r/GalaxyS6/comments/3wh8mt/i_accidentally_deleted_my_app_drawer_icon_on_my/cxwagb9

Comment: I'd love to know why this was downvoted. If finding a reddit comment was the expected way to resolve my question, then apologies for my asking.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but generally is a response is found by quickly Googling I can understand why

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Easy to fix. Just hard-press on the desktop until the query for Wallpapers, Widgets, Settings shows up. Select Widgets, and select (what on my list is #1) - Nova Action. Once placed, it turns into a menu with "App drawer" as the first choice, along with about 30 others. Once you have it selected, move it to your desired spot, either on the desktop, or in the dock, or whereever.

Comment: Perfect... I was scouring the settings thinking if have to uninstall and reinstall the app. Any idea why that happened? What to avoid in the future?

Comment: I think I was trying to make the dock scroll, so I was looking at infinite scroll, with sweep left, and right.

Comment: I found out why this happened... From Nova Settings > Dock > Dock Icons, I had switched it to be set to 1.  The way Nova operates, is the App Drawer icon by default is in the Number 3 position  If you have the Dock Icon number set to 2 or 1, the App Drawer Icon will not appear